# Play: building Json wrapper with Writes throws error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following class

```
case class User(sk: Int, userid: String)
```

and the following Writes to define Json field names:

```
      implicit val userWrites = new Writes[User] {
        def writes(user: User) = Json.obj(
          "sk" -> user.sk,
          "uid" -> user.userid
        )
      }
```

The error that I get in the `sk` field line is `Type mismatch, expected: (String, Json.JsValueWrapper), actual (String,Int)`

What is this error and how should be fixed?

Comment: When do you get this error? When trying to do what?

Comment: I get this error in IntelliJ IDEA while editing the code

Comment: Can you add the imports you have in your code?

Comment: It should works. where did you define that implicit val?